# Binding variables by name in batch and sqlplus

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I am trying to automate the running of my sql scripts with the use of batch and sqlplus. And I would like to know what is the correct way to bind variables by name.
I want to get something like this:

text of batch file:

```
set car = 'Audi'
set year = 2015
echo @script.sql :car = car :year = year | sqlplus login/password@host
```

text of script.sql:

```
set markup csv on
set echo off
set termout off
set pagesize 40000
set feedback off
spool export1.csv
@script1 :car = &car :year = &year
spool export2.csv
@script2 :car = &car :year = &year
spool export3.csv
@script3 :car = &car :year = &year
spool off
set markup csv off
```

text of script1.sql:

```
select * from t
where t.car like &car
and t.year = &year
```

Comment: Best guess; change, `set car = 'Audi'`, to `Set "car='Audi'"`, `set year = 2015` to `Set "year=2015"` and `:car = car :year = year ...` to `:car = %car% :year = %year% ...`. _You probably don't need to include the single quotes around your `Audi` string either_.

Comment: @Compo Why do I need to use double quotes after set? In [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_variables.htm) batch tutorial they don't use double quotes. Thank you for the mention of percent sign, I forgot about it. Do I need to use `'&car'`instead of `&car` in last sql statement? (I read that when binding by position I should use `'&1'`)

Comment: It appears to me that you have not followed the advice from your tutorial site anyhow. Please also note that, I know better than the person who created your tutorial. I would strongly suggest that you completely ignore their `SET /A` section, because it is just plain wrong.